# Validate Old Password Before Change Password

Tags: c#, active-directory, change-password

I tried to change password my account in `LDAP` using [`ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.ChangePassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.changepassword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, userIsOnline: true);
changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

If i enter wrong old password, the `ChangePassword` return false.
My question is: is false result from `ChangePassword` method means my old password is wrong? If not, how can i detect if I enter wrong password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MembershipUser.ChangePassword()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns true if the update was successful. It does not provide any information if the oldpassword has been wrong or not.

As this method calls the [ChangePassword()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.changepassword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the underlaying membership provider it could also throw an exception if the membership provider has restriction on e.g the size of the password which the new password didn`t match.

> Throws ArgumentException if
>
> - newPassword is less than the minimum password size specified in the [MinRequiredPasswordLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.minrequiredpasswordlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property
> - newPassword contains fewer than the number of non-alphabetic characters specified in the [MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property
> - newPassword fails validation by the regular expression defined in the [PasswordStrengthRegularExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.passwordstrengthregularexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.
>
> Throws MembershipPasswordException if
>
> - newPassword does not meet the complexity requirements defined by the Active Directory server.

To check your old password you can use the [MembershipProvider.ValidateUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validateuser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: yeah, I think `validateUser` is the only way to check my old password. Thanks!